# Missing parenthesis in display math within text within display math

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, displaystyle, text-mode

I'm trying to work out how to recursively nest text and math mode. The following example seems to fail to compile, and does not render the `\right)`:

```
% "text, {$$\int$$}, text" is an arbitrary string provided by software I
% do not control, 
$$ \operatorname{foo}\left( \text{text, {$$\int$$}, text} \right)$$
```

Is there a simple way to make this work?

Comment: You cannot use `$$...$$` within `\text`. I guess you want simply `\text{text, $\int$, text}`.

Comment: Is the a text environment I can enter from math mode within which `$$` _can_ be used?

Comment: Sorry, what but should that exactly do? `$$` (which shouldn't be really used in LaTeX anyway) enters display math mode, so you are trying to enter display math within display math. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My motivation is computational - in python have a function `sympy.latex(x)` which must return _math_-mode latex, but for some `x` the only thing available to me is `x._repr_latex_()` which returns _text_-mode latex. I'm looking for the best way of converting the latter to the former, while breaking as few constructs as possible. This question addresses failings the naive approach of `math_mode = "\\text{" + text_mode + "}"`

Comment: just use single dollars, `$$` is not latex syntax and makes display math which is not what you want here.

Comment: it's python: you must be able to regex replace `$$` by `$`  to fix the returned string before using it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sure, but I was really trying to avoid having to write a latex parser to deal with cases like `\$$`, `\\$$`, etc.

Comment: @Eric well, currently it works in no cases. If you replace $$ by $ it will work in all but the 0.00001% of cases where you have a `\$` immediately before a `$`, so on balance, a win.

Answer (score 1):

The software you're using is flawed and there's essentially no safe method for making such generated code to work.

The problem is that `\text` eventually makes an `\hbox` in which the code is typeset using *restricted horizontal mode* where `$$` has a peculiar behavior. Since display math makes no sense, TeX simply considers `$$` as an empty math formula, when in restricted horizontal mode. So your `\int` appears *outside* math mode and an error ensues.

TeX now tries to enter math mode before rescanning `\int`, then finds the closing `$` which ends math mode. It finds another one, which starts again math mode and now it finds a misplaced `}`. Another error.

Fix the software producing that code, which is bad LaTeX under many other respects. To begin with, `$$` should ***never*** be used in LaTeX.

Comment: _"To begin with, $$ should never be used in LaTeX."_ - it would be helpful to know what should be used in its place.

Comment: @Eric `\[` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69854/1090  But you do not want either here. `$$\int$$` is a full width display, it has vertical space a math display the full width of the page then more vertical space. It makes no sense to place it between commas and parenthesis as in your example. You _want_ inline math here not just avoiding the error message.

Comment: _"Fix the software producing that code, which is bad LaTeX under many other respects"_ - I do not have the power to fix the universe - the code returning `text $$\int$$ text` is in this example coming from a hypothetical third-party package, via a very lax interface specification I also do not control.